# How do I hide a Form using Nativebase?

Tags: react-native, native-base

I've got a Form that I'd like to programmatically hide/show, but am not able to figure out how to do so.  I'd imagine there's a tag to do it similar to the "disabled" tag, but I just can't seem to find out what it is.  Whatever the magic keyword Google needs to show me the answer is one I can't think of!

So, for example of what I want to do:

```
<Form visible={this.isFormComplete}>
```

So far after failing to find anything helpful on the Nativebase site and via Googling, I've tried "show", "hide", "hidden", and "visible" tags, but none seem to have any effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about a simple conditional rendering like :

```
{this.isFormComplete && <Form/>}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should declare a variable in your state then you can use your state variable in your return statement.

```
state = {
    visible: true
}

{this.state.visible ? <Component /> : null}
```